# How to authenticate end-users using Firebase Authentication from a CLI application

Tags: node.js, firebase, authentication, command-line-interface, client

## Summary

A CLI application, let's call it `friendly_chat`, needs Firebase Authentication for end-users. The CLI can be written in any language for which there is a Firebase Authentication SDK, or it can be written using low-level access to the [Firebase REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth). The objective is to be able to:

```sh
friendly_chat login
```

and have the CLI open the web-browser to sign-in the user to the Firebase App (say using the Google OAuth 2.0 provider), then return the access token to the CLI. Now the CLI can use the access token to retrieve userinfo from the https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo API endpoint or other APIs.

I'm guessing that the OAuth 2.0 flow would be the one for [Installed Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#installed) a.k.a. [Native Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252).

## Details

*Please note that this question is not about the Firebase CLI and the* `firebase login` *command which can be used to authenticate a developer to their Firebase account, however, since the Firebase CLI does open a web-browser to perform the authentication, it is proof that it can be done*.

Things I have tried so far: Node.js, Ruby, and [AppAuth](https://appauth.io/):

### Node.js

Although most use cases are for Node.js on the server to serve a web app, I think we should be able to use Node.js on the client from the command line interface (CLI). I understand that, if I were using node.js on the server, I would need to use the Firebase Admin SDK.
However, according to [Supported environments for the Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/environments-js-sdk#other_environments), I think I should be able to authenticate to Firebase from a Node.js (Client) CLI, and according to this screenshot:

[image: Firebase API Reference]

it seems that Firebase provides a "Node.js (Client)" SDK, in addition to the Javascript Web SDK (version 9 and version 8). So, I read the docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth but whenever a reference is made to Firebase Authentication (such as a link to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), that document does not mention anything about the Node.js Client; it mentions clients such as iOS, Android, and Web.

In anycase, I thought I would try to get something working, so I tried the following code (taken from [Firebase web codelab](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#0)
:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

# Filename: index.js

'use strict';

console.log('*** chatbox ***');

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

import {
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithPopup,
  signOut,
} from 'firebase/auth';

import { getFirebaseConfig } from './firebase-config.js';


const firebaseAppConfig = getFirebaseConfig();

initializeApp(firebaseAppConfig)

// Signs-in Friendly Chat.
async function signIn() {
  var provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  await signInWithPopup(getAuth(), provider);
}

// Signs-out of Friendly Chat.
function signOutUser() {
  signOut(getAuth());
}

signIn();
```

but when I execute:

```
node index.js
```

I'm getting the error that the operation is not supported in this environment:

```
auth-from-cli/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node/index-da4673cf.js:508
    return _DEFAULT_AUTH_ERROR_FACTORY.create.apply(_DEFAULT_AUTH_ERROR_FACTORY, tslib.__spreadArray([authOrCode], rest));
                                              ^

FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment).
    at createErrorInternal (/Users/alain/code/try/Google/Firebase/auth-from-cli/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node/index-da4673cf.js:508:47)
    at _createError (/Users/alain/code/try/Google/Firebase/auth-from-cli/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node/index-da4673cf.js:484:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alain/code/try/Google/Firebase/auth-from-cli/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node/index-da4673cf.js:7047:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alain/code/try/Google/Firebase/auth-from-cli/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node/index.js:5:13) {
  code: 'auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment',
  customData: {}
}
```

#### Questions:

1. So, could it be that signInWithPopup() only works from inside the web-browser?
2. I don't understand how to use the `firebase` global namespace as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase)
3. It seems that the auth package from the Javascript SDK for Web version 9 (which has sample code like [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#signinwithpopup) is quite different from the firebase.auth package from the Node.js (Client) SDK (whose sample code I cannot get to work:

```
var defaultAuth = firebase.auth();
                  ^

ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
```

### Ruby

I tried the [Simple REST Clients for Google APIs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client) which uses the [Google Auth Library for Ruby](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby) for authentication.

Although it worked, it only authenticates with Google as the OAuth 2.0 provider. Since it does not authenticate with Firebase, no user gets created in the Firebase Authentication table in my Firebase App.

### AppAuth for JS

Similar to Ruby above, the [sample code](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS/blob/master/src/node_app/index.ts) only authenticates with Google and not with Firebase, so it doesn't create the user in the Firebase Authentication table.

### Advanced: Authenticate with Firebase in Node.js

I found [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#expandable-3) but it says:

> To authenticate with Firebase in a Node.js application...

but I think in this case, they mean a Node.js webapp (and not Node.js Client, as referenced above) so they are using the Javascript Web SDK (v9 and v8) in the examples but they say nothing about Node.js (Client) SDK.

Similarly for [Advanced: Handle the sign-in flow manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#expandable-2)

Comment: `signInWithPopup` needs the DOM. How do you expect it to show a popup in a node Env? Other methods like `signInWithEmailAndPassword` work. If you'd like to use the authentication providers, you'll have to create a special route on your web-based, then redirect to it from Node, have the web app auth the user, get the token, and then pass the token back to node. The flow would be similar to what `firebase login` does

Comment: Hey! I'm working on something similar, did you figure it out?

Comment: @d-s No, sorry.